# Where can I purchase push button electrical switches?

Tags: wiring, switch

Our old house has push button light switches.  I would like to find some modern replica switches and face plates for use in some electrical improvements.  I have checked at our local home improvement stores and our one (very small) local electrical supply house they did not have any.  Is there a online source?   [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Amazon shows them as [available](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002EW9LM). Search for 'push button light switch' to find more variants (including 3 way and dimmer units).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.kyleswitchplates.com/push-button-light-switches/ will get you what you are looking for